# Finding the higest value in a loop

Tags: php, sorting, logic

I am trying to return the highest percentage value along with all the other information like name,average, percentage, color etc in the array.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {  
    $name = getName($value);
    $average = getAverage($value);
    $percentage = getPercentage($value);
    $color = getColor($value);

    return $percentage;
}
```

How can i implement the solution to find the desired value (highest percentage) and return it If an array. I am thinking sorting can be one way but i am still not clear how should i do it.

Comment: can you supply an example of the array data?

Comment: Post your array structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$percentage1=0;
$datas=array();
foreach ($array as $value) {

$name = getName($value);
$average = getAverage($value);
$percentage = getPercentage($value);
$color = getColor($value);

if($percentage>$percentage1)
{
    $percentage1=$percentage;
    $datas['name']=$name;
    $datas['average']=$average;
    $datas['percentage']=$percentage;
    $datas['color']=$color;
}
return $datas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the code in your question doesn't make any sense, you can use php max function to get highest value if all value in array are numbers.

For example:

```
<?php $highest_value = max($array); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the buit-in PHP sorting, you can use `usort()`. It use a custom function to sort your array.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $percentage_a = getPercentage($a);
    $percentage_b = getPercentage($b);
    if($percentage_a === $percentage_b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($percentage_a > $percentage_b)? -1 : 1;
});
return array(
    "name" => getName($array[0]),
    "average" => getAverage($array[0]),
    "percentage" => getPercentage($array[0]),
    "color" = getColor($array[0]));
```

Then, your array is sorted with the highest percentage first.

If you don't want anonymous function, you can juste define it and call usort with its name :

```
function getMaxPercentage($a, $b){
    $percentage_a = getPercentage($a);
    $percentage_b = getPercentage($b);
    if($percentage_a === $percentage_b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($percentage_a > $percentage_b)? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, 'getMaxPercentage');
return return array(
    "name" => getName($array[0]),
    "average" => getAverage($array[0]),
    "percentage" => getPercentage($array[0]),
    "color" = getColor($array[0]));
```